# Largest Word Circle

Tags: word

My previous word puzzle failed miserably, so I am going to try again.

Can you place *n* characters in a circle, such that a **distinct** word is formed when you read *n* characters clockwise starting from any character? For example, if you place the characters "e", "a" and "t" in a circle you will form three words: "eat", "ate" and "tea". What is the largest n for which such a *word circle* exists? I will accept words that are found in the SOWPODS [dictionary](https://www.wordgamedictionary.com/sowpods/download/sowpods.txt).

Comment: What exactly counts as a "word"?

Comment: words must be from the linked dictionary

Comment: It appears that there are several different dictionaries there - which one in particular are you using? (Also, if that link goes down, we likely won't be able to answer the puzzle - I'd recommend using a particular well-known word list, such as UKACD, SOWPODS, or SCOWL.)

Comment: I changed the link to SOWPODS

Comment: This puzzle would become significantly more interesting if the two ns didn't have to have the same value.

Comment: @GregMartin I agree. Feel free to post the new version.

Comment: I just noticed this with ate/eat/tea and was about to post this exact puzzle. Guess it deserves an up vote then.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**4 letters:** It appears that there is a length 4 "word circle".

> ALAN, LANA, ANAL, NALA

is the only one that [Qat](https://quinapalus.com/qat.html) finds for 4 letters. All of these are acceptable Scrabble words in the SOWPODS dictionary, apparently.

**5 letters?** Qat's "union" dictionary combines many different word lists, some of which have many 'non-words' (<s>*cough cough BNP cough*</s>). This list gives the following as options: `ALANG`, `AREST`, `ATEST`, `ATHER`, `ESTON`, and all of their cyclic permutations. None of those have even *three* Scrabble-legal words.

So 4 letters is likely the best you can do, for any reasonable definition of "English word".

---

The queries I used were:

4 letters: `ABCD;BCDA;CDAB;DABC;|ABCD|=4;!=AB`

5 letters: `ABCDE;BCDEA;CDEAB;DEABC;EABCD;|ABCDE|=5;!=AB`

Comment: Nice work! What a nice tool this Qat is.

Comment: I wonder if you can do better by also allowing counter-clockwise words?  I mean, obviously it's even less likely that you'd get all 10 possibilities in 5 letters, but you might get 3/10 instead of just 2/5.  I.e.: What's the most 5-letter words you can get going in either direction around a circle of 5 letters?  (I'd make it a new question, but it seems like a simple modification to your query would answer it pretty quickly...)

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Counterclockwise rotations are equivalent to clockwise rotations; just read the cycle in reverse.

Comment: @merrybot Yeah, but one circle allowing *both* clockwise *and* counter-clockwise would give you more words.  So, e.g. OTSP in a circle allows SPOT, STOP, POTS. and TOPS.

Comment: Counterclockwise and clockwise rotations give exactly the same amount of words: `123 -> 312 -> 231` and `312 <- 231 <- 123`.